# BlackBerry Simulator doesn't show when i run android project in android studio?

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-android

I have download and install BlackBerry Simulator and run it in VMWare Machine. I have run its controller. Then, I have created a simple hello world project in android studio. Here is MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Here is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.vats.vatishs.helloworld.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is build.gradle of app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vats.vatishs.helloworld"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 18
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.+'
}
```

Then I run BlackBerry ADB Proxy Manager, and then I click on play icon of running BlackBerry simulator. Now if i run my android project by clicking on green run arrow of android studio, The BlackBerry emulator is not shown in Android device list. What I should i do to run my android code on BlackBerry simulator???

Comment: What happens if you change :appcompat-v7:18.+' to :appcompat-v7:18.0.0'

Comment: Things I've tries: Rebooting.  Installing an older version of the simulator.  Upgraded version of the simulator to the latest for VMWare (things were worst in this case as the ADB Proxy Manager didn't even detect the simulator in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following to make it appear on Android studio:

1. You need to go to Android Platform-tools folder.
2. Run the command

   ./adb connect ***IP of your running device***
3. Then, the device should appear in your Android Studio Device list.

** Same as the one you given to the BlackBerry ADB Proxy Manager